# How to combine multiple columns when searching for a user PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

How to combine multiple columns when searching for a user by last name, first name and patronymic
I have two table:

UserCheck

```
id, user_id, check_id, status, created_at
```

Check table:

```
id, birth_day, region_id, status, created_at, full_name_name, full_name_surname, full_name_patronymic
```

example of filling tables

```sql
INSERT INTO user_check (id, user_id, check_id, status, created_at) VALUES
    ('123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000', '123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174001', '123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174002', 'wait', '2020-01-05'),
    ('123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174001', '123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174002', '123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174002', 'wait', '2020-01-07'),
    ('123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174002', '123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174003', '123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174006', 'wait', '2020-01-08');

INSERT INTO check_request (id, birth_day, region_id, status, created_at, full_name_name, full_name_surname, full_name_patronymic, document_type, document_number, document_series) VALUES
    ('123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174002', '2015-02-08', '52', 'status', '2021-05-01 17:15','Ivanov', 'Ivan', 'Anatolievich'),
    ('123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174006', '2015-02-08', '52', 'status', '2021-05-01 17:15','Ivanov', 'Anton', 'Anatolievich');
```

My request to find a user

```sql
SELECT user_check.user_id, user_check.status, CONCAT_WS(' ',full_name_name ,full_name_surname, full_name_patronymic)
FROM user_check
         JOIN check_request ON check_request.Id = user_check.check_id
WHERE concat(check_request.full_name_name,' ', check_request.full_name_surname, ' ', check_request.full_name_patronymic) LIKE 'Anton';
```

Otput

```
0 rows
```

What I want: how to find a person by last name, first name or patronymic separately, for example (only Anton) or search by last name, so as not to enter completely user data, but to find matches by first name, last name or patronymic?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want wildcards in your `like`:

```
LIKE '%Anton%'
```